# Increasing the max concurrent handled request on a special wcf service

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, concurrency, task-parallel-library

I have a mock service that receives a request, loads a xml file from disk, waits 2 seconds and returns the xml content.

Now the wait is done using `Task.Delay` to prevent thread blocking.

My problem is that my application is allowing only 10 concurrent requests, while the others are waiting in the queue for the previous ones to finish.

Here is a print screen of the `Fiddler` timeline for 30 requests:

[image]

The first 10 requests finish within 2 seconds.
The second 10 requests finish within 4 seconds.
The third 10 requests finish within 6 seconds.

I've tried multiple configuration changes, registry updates and other perks while googling the solution and none of them helped me.

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

What version of OS are you using? Are you on windows server or a normal windows version? There is a limit of 10 connections on the normal windows version. try deploying to a server and test again

Comment: I noticed that there is a limit (default setting) on a "normal" Windows machine. How can I increase that setting? Where is that setting hidden? Thanks.

Comment: I dont think you can do that as you have a normal version of windows it's a hard limit to prevent you from using a normal windows version as a server. You should deploy it to a windows server and then you can either configure it in IIS or through code